# Accessing and updating an object variable,or associative array

Tags: javascript, object

This is my script, which I manged to put together using code on this link :
[Setting up a variable length two-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642199/setting-up-a-variable-length-two-dimensional-array)

```
stringWithSeper = "Panther^Pink,Green,Yellow|Dog^Hot,Top";
var blocks = stringWithSeper.split("|");
for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    temp = blocks[i].split("^");
    result[temp[0]] = temp[1].split(",");
}
```

I'm confused. What's the structure of "result" ? Is it

```
result = {"Panther":{"Pink","Green","Yellow"}, "Dog":{"Hot","Top"}}
```

If not, what is it? I've been breaking my head over this for the past 3 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer: `alert(JSON.stringify(result))`

Result: `{"Panther":["Pink","Green","Yellow"],"Dog":["Hot","Top"]}`

Comment: 1)ok,how do I access the string "pink" within "panther" ? 2) How do I add "red" to the object so that it is {"Panther":["Pink","Green","Yellow","Red"],"Dog":["Hot","Top"]} using a function ?

Comment: 1) `result["Panther"][0]` or `result.Panther[0]` . 2) `result["Panther"].push("Red")` . Basically each `result["something"]` is an array of strings. Therefore you can use this reference on how to use arrays: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array